# Case Sensitivity Kotlin / ignoreCase

Tags: kotlin, case-insensitive

I am trying to ignore case sensitivity on a string. For example, a user can put "Brazil" or "brasil" and the fun will trigger. How do I implement this? I am new to Kotlin.

```
fun questionFour() {
    val edittextCountry = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextCountry)
    val answerEditText = edittextCountry.getText().toString()

    if (answerEditText == "Brazil") {
        correctAnswers++
    }

    if (answerEditText == "Brasil") {
        correctAnswers++
    }
}
```

#### EDIT

Another person helped me write like this. My question now about this way is "Is there a cleaner way to write this?"

```
fun questionFour() {
    val edittextCountry = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextCountry)
    val answerEditText = edittextCountry.getText().toString()

    if (answerEditText.toLowerCase() == "Brazil".toLowerCase() || answerEditText.toLowerCase() == "Brasil".toLowerCase()) {
        correctAnswers++
    }
}
```

#### Answer

```
fun questionFour() {

        val edittextCountry = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextCountry)
        val answerEditText = edittextCountry.getText().toString()

        if (answerEditText.equals("brasil", ignoreCase = true) || answerEditText.equals("brazil", ignoreCase = true)) {
            correctAnswers++
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe something like: `answerEditText.toLowerCase() in listOf("brazil", "brasil")`

Comment: you can also avoid `toLowerCase` in `if` if you write `val answerEditText = edittextCountry.text.toString().toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can call the [`equals`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/equals.html) function directly, which will allow you to specify the optional parameter `ignoreCase`:

```
if (answerEditText.equals("brasil", ignoreCase = true)) {
    correctAnswers++
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

The core problem is that `==` just calls through to `equals()`, which is case sensitive. There are a few ways to solve this:

1) Lowercase the input and direct compare:

```
if (answerEditText.toLowerCase() == "brasil" ||
    answerEditText.toLowerCase() == "brazil") {
    // Do something
}
```

This is easy to understand and maintain, but if you have more than a couple of answers, it gets unwieldy.

2) Lowercase the input and test for values in a set:

```
if (answerEditText.toLowerCase() in setOf("brasil", "brazil")) {
    // Do Something
}
```

Perhaps define the set as a constant somewhere (in a companion object?) to avoid recreating it a few times. This is nice and clear, useful when you have a lot of answers.

3) Ignore the case and compare via `.equals()` method:

```
if (answerEditText.equals("Brazil", true) ||
    answerEditText.equals("Brasil", true)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Similar to option 1, useful when you only have a coupe of answers to deal with.

4) Use a case insensitive regular expression:

```
val answer = "^Bra(s|z)il$".toRegex(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
if (answer.matches(answerEditText)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Again, create the `answer` regex once and store it somewhere to avoid recreating. I feel this is an overkill solution.

Answer (score 1):

We created extension function and use it so we can avoid specifying second parameter.

```
fun String.equalsIgnoreCase(other: String?): Boolean {
    if (other == null) {
        return false
    }

    return this.equals(other, true)
}

println("California".equalsIgnoreCase("CALIFORNIA"))
```

Comment: There's no need for the if (other == null) check. The equals() function, takes a nullable as a parameter