# Case insensitive when

Tags: kotlin

Is it somehow possible to make `when` `String` comparison case insensitive by default?

```
when (subtype.toLowerCase()) {
    MessagingClient.RTC_SUBTYPE.sdp.toString().toLowerCase() -> onSDPMessageReceived(topic, sender, data!!)
    MessagingClient.RTC_SUBTYPE.bye.toString().toLowerCase() -> onRTCBYEMessageReceived(topic, sender)
    MessagingClient.RTC_SUBTYPE.negotiationOffer.toString().toLowerCase() -> onNegotiationOfferMessageReceived(sender, data!!)
}
```

This has too much repetetive code! Also note that `MessagingClient.RTC_SUBTYPE` is `enum class` and `subtype` on the first line is received from some client, so we must treat it accordingly.

Comment: You could perhaps use `equals()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49349674/case-sensitivity-kotlin-ignorecase

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would convert `subtype` to `MessagingClient.RTC_SUBTYPE` like so:

```
val subtypeEnum = MessagingClient.RTC_SUBTYPE.values().firstOrNull {
   it.name.equals(subtype, ignoreCase = true) 
} ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("${subtype} no value of MessagingClient.RTC_SUBTYPE match")
```

And then use it in `when`

```
when (subtypeEnm) {
    MessagingClient.RTC_SUBTYPE.sdp -> onSDPMessageReceived(topic, sender, data!!)
    MessagingClient.RTC_SUBTYPE.bye -> onRTCBYEMessageReceived(topic, sender)
    MessagingClient.RTC_SUBTYPE.negotiationOffer -> onNegotiationOfferMessageReceived(sender, data!!)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var s1 =editText.text.toString()
var s2=textView_.text
var s3 =s1.equals(s2 ,true)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also, since you seem to struggle with it: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help